# DBFField number type

Tags: java, dbf

I have code which forms dbf file, but two fields have numeric type and one of them has 45,05 value and another one 45, but I can't writing two different values into dbf file, I got like 45 and 45 instead of  45,05 and 45!

```
switch (metaData.getColumnType(i + 1)) {
  case 91:
    arrfiled[recNum].setName(temp);
    arrfiled[recNum].setDataType(DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_D);
    break;
  case 93:
    arrfiled[recNum].setName(temp);
    arrfiled[recNum].setDataType(DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_D);
    break;
  case 2:
    arrfiled[recNum].setName(temp);
    arrfiled[recNum].setDataType(DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_N);
    arrfiled[recNum].setFieldLength(
        metaData.getPrecision(i + 1) == 0 ? 10 : metaData.getPrecision(i + 1));
    break;
  case 3:
    arrfiled[recNum].setName(temp);
    arrfiled[recNum].setDataType(DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_N);
    arrfiled[recNum].setFieldLength(
        metaData.getPrecision(i + 1) == 0 ? 10 : metaData.getPrecision(i + 1));
    break;
  case 8:
    arrfiled[recNum].setName(temp);
    arrfiled[recNum].setDataType(DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_N);
    arrfiled[recNum].setFieldLength(
        metaData.getPrecision(i + 1) == 0 ? 10 : metaData.getPrecision(i + 1));
    break;
  default:
    arrfiled[recNum].setName(temp);
    arrfiled[recNum].setDataType(DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_C);
    arrfiled[recNum].setFieldLength(metaData.getPrecision(i + 1) > 253
                                        ? 253
                                        : metaData.getPrecision(i + 1));
    break;
}
recNum++;
}
```